# Customize style of input filter in datatable

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable

Trying to add search icon next to the input field in my Laravel Datatable. I cannot use jquery to change the text "Search:" next to my input field and change it to search icon `<i class="icon-search"></i>`, because there is no tag for this label, it make it really hard to select it. How can I achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div id="orders-table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
  <label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="orders-table">
  </label>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTable is Jquery Library. I dont understand why you cant use jquery for that. For changing search label follow [this link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/27161/change-the-text-label-for-the-table-filter-aka-search)

---

```
language: {
  search: '<i class="icon-search"></i>'
}
```

Comment: @gubera, I really think you should add the solution to the answer. A link does not tell much...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by first replacing text node ("search") by empty string then append the icon i before onput tag see below snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $input = $(".dataTables_filter").find("[type='search']");

  $input.parent().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 // here means return all node type text (textNode)
  }).each(function() {
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('Search:', '');
  });
  
  $input.before($("<i class='icon-search'></i>"));

})
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="orders-table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
  <label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="orders-table">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your effort. I find a more direct way by using the other answer.